# AttributeError: type object 'BSTNode' has no attribute 'left'

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree, treenode, inorder

I was trying to construct a Binary Search Tree in python.
This is my node class:

```
class BSTNode:
def __init__(self,val):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.val = val
```

This class contains a function called `printTree`, which is supposed to print the tree inorder. Here is the printTree function:

```
def printTree(self,val):
    if self.left is not None:
        self.left.printTree()
    print(self.val)
    if self.right is not None:
        self.right.printTree()
```

When I execute the function it gives **AttributeError: type object 'BSTNode' has no attribute 'left'**

Here is my full code:

```
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = val

    def insertNode(self,val):
        if self.val:
            if val < self.val:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = BSTNode(val)
                else:
                    self.left.insertNode(val)
            else:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = BSTNode(val)
                else:
                    self.right.insertNode(val)
        else:
            self.val = val

    def findval(self,fval):
       if (fval == self.val):
           print(str(self.val)," data found ")
       elif(fval < self.val):
            if self.left is None:
                print(str(self.val)," data not found")
            else:
                self.left.findval(fval)
       else:
           if self.right is None:
               print(str(self.val)," data not found")
           else:
               self.right.findval(fval)

    def printTree(self,val):
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.printTree()
        print(self.val)
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.printTree()
            
    

root = BSTNode(12)
root.insertNode(6)
root.insertNode(5)
root.insertNode(18)
root.insertNode(15)
root.insertNode(21)
BSTNode.printTree(BSTNode)
```

Comment: Can you share the nodes? The one where you triggered the `printTree()`.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano Here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/3qkjnCA5

Comment: I added an answer which I updated just now. You could try either of the 2 options and choose what better fits your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are calling `printTree()` without arguments:

```
self.left.printTree()
...
self.right.printTree()
```

Yet, you defined it to accept `val`, which is just unused by the way:

```
def printTree(self,val):
```

Replace it to:

```
def printTree(self):
```

2. The method `printTree()` is an instance method, not a `@classmethod` nor `@staticmethod`. That means it requires an active instance/object of `BSTNode` to be called which will be passed as the `self` argument. So this call is incorrect:

```
BSTNode.printTree(BSTNode)
```

It must be:

```
root.printTree(BSTNode)
```

Then considering my point-1 above, finally it should be:

```
root.printTree()
```

Where `root` is your current active instance of type `BSTNode`.

After those fixes, it would be successful

```
5
6
12
15
18
21
```

---

#### Alternative Solution

If you don't want `printTree()` to be an instance method, make it a `@staticmethod` instead.

```
class BSTNode:
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def printTree(self):  # I named it self to be close to your real implementation. Ideally, rename it to something like "node" or "obj" to avoid confusion since this is not an instance method.
        if self.left is not None:
            self.printTree(self.left)
        print(self.val)
        if self.right is not None:
            self.printTree(self.right)
...
BSTNode.printTree(root)
```

This will produce the same output.